# Can I put two 30A double pole breaker s and a few other 15A breaker s

Tags: electrical-panel, subpanel

[image]

Can I put two 30A breakers and a few 15A breaker s all in my 60A subpanel ?

The pic shows the existing breakers and I want to put one more 30A and one 15 A for a laundry set.   Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: What is the existing 30A already powering?  What are all the other circuits so far?  What part of your house does this power?

Comment: It looks like there is room,  but we would to know what your loads are, If this is your main panel and you have an electric dryer with Gas heat, stove / ovens and water heater, it might be possible , but we do need to understand what the total load is and what the new 30 amp breaker is for. If the new device was not used at the same time as the dryer if it is a dryer it is possible. But more information is needed, some may also ask the square footage as this is used in load calculations. In the past smaller panels were allowed in homes but today a 100 amp panel is the standard.

Comment: Can you post the directory label info on the inside of the door for this panel? Or otherwise tell us what the various breakers power?

Comment: The existing 30A is for dryer and two or three 15A  circuits are for kitchen plug and other small space heaters.  Fridge may also be taking one , I don't know others.       The new 30 A will be for another  dryer .   Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: What are the chances of both dryers being used at once?